# Outer product with dates

Tags: r, outer-join, lubridate

Given a vector of datetime values, I needed to create a `data.frame` containing datetimes at `0:10` hours past each original datetime - the first column 0 hours past, the second column 1 hour past, etc.

I had some trouble finding a way to do this easily using `lubridate` stuff.  I thought this should work:

```
rt <- ymd_hms(c("2011-11-03 19:24:12", "2011-10-28 20:48:21",
  "2011-11-04 10:06:14", "2011-10-31 17:10:05", "2011-10-28 06:35:59"))
result <- outer(rt, hours(0:10), "+")
```

But various parts in that pipeline break down.  Ultimately I get this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid 'times' argument
```

which seems to come from `rep.POSIXct()`'s or `rep.period()`'s inability to handle a non-unit-length `times` argument.  Or something.

And it probably wouldn't have worked anyway, because `outer()` returns a matrix, and date objects, even POSIXct dates (which are internally just integers) it seems can't be elements in a matrix.

What I figured out that worked (just to get the times, not to put them in a data frame), after about 10 other guesses, was this:

```
with_tz(do.call(c, lapply(rt, function(x) x+hours(0:3))), tz(rt[1]))
```

The `with_tz()` addition is necessary because `c()` loses the timezone attribute.  I also have to do `do.call(c, lapply(...))` rather than just `sapply(...)` because `sapply()` loses the fact that it's a date.

Maybe another alternative would be to create a data frame by doing `do.call(cbind, ...)` or something.

In general, it would be great if, whenever we find R date/time tasks that seem conceptually easy but require a lot of gymnastics before finding a solution, we could remove the roadblocks by making changes to `lubridate`, or whatever.  I'm thinking this might be one of those times. =)

Comment: I think @hadley would be delighted if you submitted a patch to `lubridate`. You can submit an issue (and your patched code) here: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues

Comment: I've actually done that for 2 other issues (see https://github.com/kenahoo/lubridate/) over the past couple months, and @hadley was appreciative, but they aren't getting picked up.  Lubridate hasn't had a commit since May, it seems like it might be in a development lull.

Comment: I think you should edit the title. You already admit that outer can't possibly return date time values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't use `outer()`, but I think it gets you where you want.  It does use `plyr`.

```
library("lubridate")
library("plyr")

rt <- ymd_hms(c("2011-11-03 19:24:12", "2011-10-28 20:48:21",
  "2011-11-04 10:06:14", "2011-10-31 17:10:05", "2011-10-28 06:35:59"))

offsets = 0:10
names(offsets) <- offsets

dat <- data.frame(llply(offsets, function(offset){rt+hours(offset)}))
```

Giving names to the `offsets` variable just makes the column names of the `data.frame` nicer.

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ X0 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 19:24:12" "2011-10-28 20:48:21" ...
 $ X1 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 20:24:12" "2011-10-28 21:48:21" ...
 $ X2 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 21:24:12" "2011-10-28 22:48:21" ...
 $ X3 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 22:24:12" "2011-10-28 23:48:21" ...
 $ X4 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 23:24:12" "2011-10-29 00:48:21" ...
 $ X5 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-04 00:24:12" "2011-10-29 01:48:21" ...
 $ X6 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-04 01:24:12" "2011-10-29 02:48:21" ...
 $ X7 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-04 02:24:12" "2011-10-29 03:48:21" ...
 $ X8 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-04 03:24:12" "2011-10-29 04:48:21" ...
 $ X9 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-04 04:24:12" "2011-10-29 05:48:21" ...
 $ X10: POSIXct, format: "2011-11-04 05:24:12" "2011-10-29 06:48:21" ...
```

UPDATE:

Ken's comment about `ldply()` versus `data.frame(llply())` made me realize there is another way to approach this.

```
dat <- ldply(rt, `+`, hours(0:10))
```

which gives

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ V1 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 12:24:12" "2011-10-28 13:48:21" ...
 $ V2 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 13:24:12" "2011-10-28 14:48:21" ...
 $ V3 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 14:24:12" "2011-10-28 15:48:21" ...
 $ V4 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 15:24:12" "2011-10-28 16:48:21" ...
 $ V5 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 16:24:12" "2011-10-28 17:48:21" ...
 $ V6 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 17:24:12" "2011-10-28 18:48:21" ...
 $ V7 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 18:24:12" "2011-10-28 19:48:21" ...
 $ V8 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 19:24:12" "2011-10-28 20:48:21" ...
 $ V9 : POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 20:24:12" "2011-10-28 21:48:21" ...
 $ V10: POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 21:24:12" "2011-10-28 22:48:21" ...
 $ V11: POSIXct, format: "2011-11-03 22:24:12" "2011-10-28 23:48:21" ...
```

Note that, in addition to different column names (V1-V11 rather than X0-X10), these dates have been converted to local time (PDT, in my case):

```
> dat$V1
[1] "2011-11-03 12:24:12 PDT" "2011-10-28 13:48:21 PDT"
[3] "2011-11-04 03:06:14 PDT" "2011-10-31 10:10:05 PDT"
[5] "2011-10-27 23:35:59 PDT"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Am I correct that the reason you do `data.frame(llply(...))` rather than just `ldply(...)` is to recombine by column, rather than row?  It might be nice if `ldply` (and other `*dply` functions) had an argument indicating direction of join.

Comment: @KenWilliams, that's correct. `ldply` would combine the results of the function call (here, adding hours to the rt vector) as rows, where returning them as lists and then calling `data.frame` makes each list a column.  Your comment does point out another way to do it, though, by iterating the other way.  I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Nice idea!  I'd never thought of using `l*ply` like that for an outer product.